# Basis for neighborhoods at $a \in \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm a math undergrad and I decided to start self-studying topology, so I bought Mendelson, *Introduction to Topology*. As the book has no solutions, I'm not sure whether if the activities I'm doing are correct. As I struggled a bit with the definition given of a basis for system of neighborhoods at "a", I would like to know if my answers to the following exercise is correct.

*Show that no finite collection of subsets of $\mathbb R$ can be a basis for the system of neighborhoods at "a".(Chapter 1, Section 4)*

**My answer:**
Suppose that there exists B such that B is a basis for the system of neighborhoods at "a", where $|B| = n,n \in \mathbb N$. Let $I_k \in B$, then as $I_k$ is a neighborhood of "a", there exists $\delta_k > 0: B(a;\delta_k) \subset I_k$. Set $\delta = min \{\delta_k : k \in \{1..n\} \}$. Then the open ball $B(a;\epsilon), \epsilon < \delta (e.g. \epsilon = \delta /2)$ is a neighborhood of "a", but there exists $x_k \in \mathbb R: x_k \in I_k$ and $x_k \notin B(a;\epsilon)$, for every $k \in \{1..n\}$; just choose $x_k = a + \delta_k - 1/m$ with $\delta_k - 1/m > \epsilon$, for certain $m \in \mathbb N$. Then, $d(x_k,a) < \delta$ but $d(x_k,a) > \epsilon$; thus no $I_k \in B$ verifies that $I_k \subset B(a;\epsilon)$. Therefore, B is not a basis for the system of neighborhoods which is a contradiction. Hence, B cannot be finite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that idea is fine, but of course you'll need a $\delta_k$ for $I_k$ (which you probably mean but did not write). Also, the proof that $B(a, \frac{\delta}{2})$ does not contain any $I_k$ is somewhat sloppy ("for certain $m \in \Bbb N$"; which one?), e..g you probably mean something like $x_k = a+ \delta_k - \frac1m$?..

A proof with less details; more conceptual:

Suppose $B_1,\ldots B_n$ are a base at $a$. Then $O_a:=\bigcap_{i=1}^n B_i$ also an open neighbourhood of $a$ and as $\{a\}$ is not open, there is some $b \in O_a$ such that $b \neq a$. Then $X\setminus \{b\}$ is open (as all singletons are closed), contains $a$, and by construction $ B_n \nsubseteq X\setminus \{b\}$ as witnessed by $b$, for any $n$. So the $B_n$ do not form a local base at $a$ after all..

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x_k = a+\delta_k - 1/m$ but I wrote it incorrectly (I have already changed it). Afterwards, I thought that you can get $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $a + \delta_k - 1/m > \delta / 2$ as integers do not have an upper bound, that's why I assume the existence of such $m \in \mathbb N$.